# onItemClickListener implemented on other rows of custom ListView

Tags: android, database, listview, view, android-arrayadapter

**--EDITED--**

**What I have:**

2 ListViews of different colors

I am using **CustomListViewAdapter**

**What I want to do:**

1-On an item click of first ListView, the color of this View will be set to the same color of the second and the TextView's text color will be white instead of black.

2-When clicking another item, the first item will return like it was.

**Problem:**

Everything went great till I noticed that when I click an item and scrolling, other views are changing background color and text color too..

**In getView() in CustomListAdapater:**

**Code:**

```
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemshow, null);

vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("myList","isClicked");
            if(PreviousView!=null){
                PreviousView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.nametext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.quantitytext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.pricetext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#330000"));
            holder.nametext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.quantitytext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.pricetext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            PreviousView = v;
        }
    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem finally.. If anyone's interested I'll post my code :) I wont post it now since there are not a lot of views..

Also I recommend anyone who's having trouble reading this article:

http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a default color for your views in `getView` method of your `listviews`. The reason this happens is because views are recycled in `listview`. If you want to have more control of your views you better create your own adapter and override `getView()` method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.itemshow, null);

vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.i("myList","isClicked");
            if(PreviousView!=null){
                PreviousView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                holder.nametext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.quantitytext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                holder.pricetext.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#330000"));
            holder.nametext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.quantitytext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            holder.pricetext.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            PreviousView = vi;
        }
    });

    vi.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); // setup default color here
// for your TextView's as well, if you change them on click
    }
```

Comment: I'm not using a CustomListViewAdapter that's the problem.. I'm using a SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: I had so much trouble using a custom adapter that's why I switched to this method instead..

Comment: Ok so I went and changed back to a custom adapter.. But I also found myself at the same problem. 
I re-posted my new code if you can help it would be much apperciated

Comment: You need to explicitly setup a background in your `getView()` method, i.e.  v.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

Comment: Ok so I setup a background color for the view and text color for the TextViews. Now when clicking and scrolling up and down, the view come back to it's original color and the text colors too :/

Comment: After debugging, the getView() isn't called actually only for 10 times although there are more rows. Maybe it's because of that since the 11th row is affected like the first one.